# Identify strings inside a vector using R

Tags: r, string

Can anyone help me in this problem?

I have a vector like this:

```
vec1 <- c("10F/I/V", "33F", "36I", "54A/L/M/S/T/V", "62V", "82A/C/F/G", "84V", "90M")
```

And another one like this:

```
vec2 <- c("10F", "10L", "10I", "33G", "47A", "54A", "54T", "62V")
```

I want to compute the result equal 3, because vec2 has the strings "10F" and "10I" that belongs to the same string "10F/I/V", it also has the strings "54A" and "54T" that belongs to "54A/L/M/S/T/V" and the "62V".

Thanks!

Comment: not really sure what you're trying to accomplish. what result are you hoping for?

Comment: Maybe `sum(substr(vec1, 1, 3) %in% vec2)`, but this is not extensible to scenarios where the match occurs in the middle of the vec1 element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expand your original vector `vec1` to explicitly construct strings like `54A`, `54L`, `54M`... Once you have that, you can find any pattern and call "match" as you go.

```
vec1 <- c("10F/I/V", "33F", "36I", "54A/L/M/S/T/V", "62V", "82A/C/F/G", "84V", "90M")

vec2 <- c("10F", "10L", "10I", "33G", "47A", "54A", "54T", "62V")


out1 <- mapply(x = gsub("(^\\d+)(.*$)", "\\1", vec1),
               y = strsplit(gsub("\\d+", "", vec1), "/"),
               FUN = function(x, y) {
                 # expands the vector to make comparisons easy using regex
                 xy <- paste(x, y, sep = "")
                 # finds individual combination
                 m <- sapply(xy, FUN = grepl, vec2)
                 # finds if strings appears in original element (element is a column)
                 apply(m, MARGIN = 2, any)  
               })

> sapply(out1, any)
   10    33    36    54    62    82    84    90 
 TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE 
> sum(sapply(out1, any))
[1] 3
```